# Can't boolean with geometry node'd object?

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, boolean-modifier

It doesn't appear that you can do boolean operations with an object that has been generated from geometry nodes, and I'm trying to understand why - or am I doing something wrong?

As a simple example, I'm trying to get the below scene's `Plane` and subtract `Plane turned into Cubes` with a boolean difference operator. It lets me do this, but if I hide `Plane turned into Cubes`, I'm expecting the parts that look like cubes to be missing from the plane, which it's not. I tried applying the Geometry Nodes modifier on `Plane turned into Cubes` but it didn't let me do this, saying "evaluated geometry from modifier does not contain a mesh" - which presumably is related to why I can't do the boolean operation? Not sure how to interpret this.

[image]

[image: trying to boolean things]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add a *Realize Instances* node after *Instances on Points*.